# Positioning the bootstrap navbar 100px below the top in order to make room for logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am having trouble positioning the bootstrap navbar at a constant position 100px below the top of the page in order to make room for a logo. I ve tried everything in the CSS and nothing seems to work. Could someone help me out please?

```
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default  " role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">

                <li><a href="">| Home |</a></li>

                <li><a href="">| About |</a></li>

                <li><a href="">| History |</a></li>

                <li><a href="">| Members |</a></li>

                <li><a href="">| News |</a></li>

                <li><a href="">| Publications |</a></li>

                <li><a href="">| Contact Us |</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
`.navbar-default{
 position:fixed;
 top:1000px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 }
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(126, 77, 29, 1);
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
color: rgba(49, 42, 103, 1);
background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(148, 89, 30, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
border-color: #94591e;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: #fff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
background-color: #fff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
background-color: #7e4d1d;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: if you don't mind, put everything at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: not sure what I am supposed to do there?

Comment: opps its http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: never used this before, and it doesn't seem to work : http://jsfiddle.net/rmzctdw9/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rmzctdw9/3/ Is this what you're looking for? If so, I won't recommend setting a constant height, instead you can try `margin-top: 20%` to ensure it's responsive.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. However now I am having trouble trying to insert a logo at the top left of the page, right above the navigation bar. Should I be using the <iframe> tag?

Comment: Thank you so much once again, I was able to solve the last little part on my own, I had too much CSS going with a couple of errors . How do I upvote this or choose you as the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, don't use iframe unless it's necessary.

**Question answered via comment.**